# Pointers and dynamically allocating arrays; EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor

This is my constructor which should "Dynamically allocate frontGuards and rearGuards arrays, create the special SNode* objects as guards, tie all the SNode objects together (both prev-next and up-down)":

```
// SkipList constructor
SkipList::SkipList(int Depth) {
    // The depth of the SkipList is given in the constructor,
    // so frontGuards and rearGuards will have to be dynamically
    // allocated arrays, using frontGuards = new SNode*[depth];
    // where for the level L0, the frontGuard will be frontGuards[0]
    // and rear guard frontGuards[0]

    FrontGuards = new SNode* [Depth];
    RearGuards = new SNode* [Depth];

    FrontGuards[0] -> Data = INT_MIN;
    RearGuards[0] -> Data = INT_MAX;
    FrontGuards[0] -> Next = RearGuards[0];
    RearGuards[0] -> Prev = FrontGuards[0];
    FrontGuards[0] -> Prev = nullptr;
    RearGuards[0] -> Next = nullptr;
    FrontGuards[0] -> UpLevel = nullptr;
    FrontGuards[0] -> DownLevel = nullptr;
    RearGuards[0] -> UpLevel = nullptr;
    RearGuards[0] -> DownLevel = nullptr;
}
```

This is my .h:

```
private:
    // private SNode
    // defined in .cpp as SkipList::SNode::SNode(int Data) ...
    struct SNode {
        // SNode stores int as data
        explicit SNode(int Data);
        // data for SNode
        int Data;
        // link to Next SNode
        SNode *Next;
        // link to Prev SNode
        SNode *Prev;
        // link to up one level
        SNode *UpLevel;
        // link to down one level
        SNode *DownLevel;
    };

    using Snode = struct Snode;

    // Depth of SkipList
    int Depth;

    // array of Depth SNode* objects as FrontGuards linking levels
    SNode **FrontGuards;

    // array of Depth SNode* objects as RearGuards linking levels
    SNode **RearGuards;
}
```

I keep getting the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) for the line "FrontGuards[0] -> Data = INT_MIN;" and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You either are not sure how pointers work, or are confused on the differences between pointers and arrays. The shown code allocates an array of pointers, but completely fails to initialize the pointers themselves, followed by attempts to dereference uninitialized pointers. Hillarity ensues. Since the shown code fails to meet all requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help], it's not clear what the actual intent of the code is, and it's not possible to make any further suggestions. P.S. Copying a small part of the homework assignment, that makes no sense on its own, doesn't really help.

Comment: could you please explain how I would initialize them?